# missing perl modules, installing kh coder in Kubuntu

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, cpan

error: Can't locate Lingua/JA/Regular/Unicode.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Lingua::JA::Regular::Unicode module)

installing missing perl modules which is required for kh-coder (https://github.com/ko-ichi-h/khcoder)

few missing modules, I have installed, but stuck now with above module, can anybody help?

```
shinigami@DeathNote:~/Downloads/programs/khcoder-master$ perl kh_coder.pl               Perl/Tk: 804.033
Can't locate Lingua/JA/Regular/Unicode.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Lingua::JA::Regular::Unicode module) (@INC contains: /home/shinigami/Downloads/programs/khcoder-master/kh_lib /home/shinigami/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.1/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/shinigami/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.1 /home/shinigami/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/shinigami/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28 /usr/share/perl/5.28 /home/shinigami/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.0 /home/shinigami/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.0/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at /home/shinigami/Downloads/programs/khcoder-master/kh_lib/kh_dictio.pm line 353.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/shinigami/Downloads/programs/khcoder-master/kh_lib/kh_dictio.pm line 353.
Compilation failed in require at /home/shinigami/Downloads/programs/khcoder-master/kh_lib/mysql_ready.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/shinigami/Downloads/programs/khcoder-master/kh_lib/mysql_ready.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at kh_coder.pl line 127.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at kh_coder.pl line 127.
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you try to install the module?

Comment: can't locate Lingua/JA/Regular/Unicode/pm

Comment: CPAN search → Lingua::JA::Regular::Unicode : Download `Lingua-JA-Regular-Unicode-0.13.tar.gz` https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/T/TO/TOKUHIROM/Lingua-JA-Regular-Unicode-0.13.tar.gz

Comment: @ratnesh *"Can't locate Lingua/JA/Regular/Unicode.pm"* That's the error you get when running the script. But how did you try to install the module?

Answer (score 0):

type as follows and hit Enter key:

> sudo cpanm Lingua::JA::Regular::Unicode